# android EditText and textformatting

Tags: android

in my custom listview that Contain an image and EditText ,and in EditText i can comment the photo ,i can give text comment max length of 50 ,when i lost the focus in EditText i want to rearrange the text in EditText in following format

EG: suppose comment contain 40 char and user can at a time directly view only 20 char,then if i lost the focus text should be rearranged that at the end there should be 3 dot

Original Comment i wirte:eg-> eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee after i lost focus it should shown as-> eeeeeeeee...

it's importent that the nothing happens to original text because these text i want to send to server, and i directly take these values,and if am replace the text by new this type of text this will create problem, also when i gain focus i need to see full text also.

i have used this android:ellipsize="end"

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a specific value for `android:ems` on your EditText if you want to use the ellipsize function as it will only truncate strings longer than the `EditText`s width. With `ems` or `maxEms` you can specify how many ems wide your `EditText` should be. Also don't forget to set `android:singleLine` to true.